# FacebookMessenger API send messages but don't get

Tags: php, facebook, messenger

I'm currently developing a messenger BOT where the BOT is on an server A hidden with a vpn.

So I have a server B which gets the request and sends it to the server A.
The problem is that I'm able to send messages and quick replies with A when I send an http request directly. But A never get curl request from B.

The second problem and the main, is that the first server don't 'always' get the request from the Facebook server.
In my code I copy past the content of php://input to text.txt on both server A and B to investigate

```
if (($response = file_get_contents("php://input")) === FALSE) {
        file_put_contents("text.txt", "error get");return false;
}
if (($json = json_encode($response)) === FALSE) {
        file_put_contents("text.txt", "decode");return false;
}
file_put_contents("text.txt", $json);
```

when I do `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"name": "linuxize", "email": "linuxize@example.com"}' myserver.com` I always get the data on server B
But when I send message on messenger, and that I should get an HTTP request to B, I don't get the request OR I get an older request which is always with the same content except the "time". But the timestamp is the same.
If anyone understand/know why I don't always get the right data in php://input it would be awesome

Comment: _“But A never get curl request from B.”_ - because B does not get any webhook requests from Facebook, or because your cURL request attempts from B to A don’t succeed in general? If the latter, then you’ll have to go and investigate, why - we know nothing about your setup, and the VPN stuff.

Comment: Regarding your second problem, what exactly _do_ you get in your log file then? Btw., that file gets _overwritten_ with each call to your script, that is probably not that helpful in debugging. I’d either write new files that contain the exact timestamp in their name, or use file_put_contents in append mode, so that it adds to the existing file, and then also add the timestamp info to each entry as well.

Comment: Then B has probably not answered the webhook request with the necessary 200 OK status in the required time frame - if that acknowledgement of having received the data is not given, then Facebook will send the same updates again. They will try for a certain time, and finally your webhook will be disabled, if its unresponsive behavior does not change.

Comment: The webhook request from facebook that B get is always the same expect the time which change, like if it was stuck
Actually i don't have access to the setup of the server and the VPN
```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"104441154954210","time":1612273140803,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"12345678"},"recipient":{"id":"12345678"},"timestamp":1612261566238,"message":{"mid":"my_mid","text":"SAV","quick_reply":{"payload":"idk"}}}]}]}
```
i can send message abcd this will still send the previous data

Comment: Yes, that is what my previous comment was in regard to already …